# Using Web Server Chrome to send External Messages to Chrome Application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am having some trouble sending message requests to my chrome application. I am using Web Server Chrome (WSC) to build a web server so I can have remote access to my application. The webpage runs perfectly fine - I have it running on my device's wlan address. However, I cannot get the webpage to send a message to my extension.

I have my connectable address in my manifest.json:

`"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://10.220.20.61:8080/*"]
  }`

On the JavaScipt for my webpage, I have the proper format as stated in the chrome documentation:

`var editorExtensionId  = "jmemdlfjenjncomlnacgbpiibcjfcnmf";
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: "http://10.220.20.61:8080/index.html"},
            function(response)
            {
                console.log("Tried to send");
            });`

And lastly, on my background.js file, I have the proper format as well:

`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse)
    {
          console.log("Recieved");
    }
  );`

Can anyone shine any light as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You might want to try using 127.0.0.1 because there may be a restriction with onMessageExternal needs to come from an https page (with an exception for localhost)

Comment: I tried to use 127.0.0.1, but I still did not get any output on my application.

Comment: Can you try using chrome.runtime.connect on the website and `chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener` and see if that works? I am using that on mp4cast.com and it is working, but I have not used onMessageExternal recently so can't say if it works for sure.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how chrome.runtime.connect works? I'm a little bit confused by the documentation..

Comment: Is your chrome extension id correct in the sendMessage? When developing, chrome generates the id from a [SHA256 of the path where it was loaded from](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/crx_file/id_util.cc?l=48).

Comment: The chrome extension ID I have is the one chrome says when I load my unpacked extension.  It's right under "Details" and above "Loaded From". It's generated by my .pem file I generated.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onMessageExternal&type= for a sample app. Unfortunately there are no example extensions that use onMessageExternal

Comment: Look also at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=343007 which has an example you can download

Comment: Found the issue - did not do "return true" at the end. Thank you for all your help!